# USAGE BINARY in COBOL program

Tags: cobol

I have the following code in a COBOL program.

```
05  WS-CHARACTER-STRING.                               
   10  WS-CHARS-LOW-VALUES     PIC X(08) VALUE X'0000'.   
   10  WS-CHARS                PIC X(08).  
.
.
.          
05  WS-BINARY                 PIC 9(18) BINARY.  
05  WS-RESULT                 PIC 9(18).  
.
.
.  
MOVE WKO-DATA-RECORD(116:8) TO WS-CHARS   
DISPLAY ' WS-CHARS:' WS-CHARS              
MOVE WS-CHARACTER-STRING    TO WS-BINARY   
DISPLAY ' WS-BINARY:' WS-BINARY          
MOVE WS-BINARY              TO WS-RESULT  
DISPLAY ' WS-RESULT:' WS-RESULT
```

The 8 chars that are being passed to WS-CHARS are different valid values. But, the output in WS-RESULT is always the same value. I put in the display messages to check and the value in WS-BINARY and WS-RESULT is the same. 
Firstly, I do not understand if this logic has any meaning. If it does, why am I getting the same value for different inputs?

Comment: Without some sort of context this is meaningless code. Can you tell us what you think might be the objective here? Until then I don't think anybody will be able to offer much help.

Answer (score 1):

An 18-digit binary only occupies eight bytes.

I don't think it is a "standard" thing for a COBOL compiler to allow the MOVE of a group field (WS-CHARACTER-STRING) to a binary field.

If you are getting a constant output, it would look like a "character" MOVE is being done to the binary field, so eight bytes from the start of WS-CHARACTER-STRING, which has a constant value. If you tell us the value (I'd suspect it is X'0000202020202020' as a decimal) we could confirm.

I can neither see nor guess any purpose in the code as it stands. I have no clue what is at 116:8. ON the face of it, MOVE WKO-DATA-RECORD(116:8) TO WS-BINARY in place of the first two MOVEs would get you varying results. Whether the results are correct depends entirely on the data, and the meaning of the data.

In general, prefixing a binary value by X'0000' and then treating that resultant field as a binary is the same as dividing by 65536, but is much faster. However, if that was the intention, the data definitions would need to be different.

Please update your question with as much information as you can, including compiler name and operating system.

Comment: Not sure of the standard, but most Cobol Compilers I have seen treat groups as a Pic-X field

Comment: Yes, and I don't think it is standard to be able to MOVE a PIC X to a BINARY. Yet in the code shown it seems to operate without a compile error - unless an error which wasn't noticed and a incomplete "object" was then run, perhaps a possibility.

Comment: Yeah, setting WS-CHARS and then moving WS-CHARACTER-STRING is giving you 2 nulls and 6 spaces, in front of the characters set.  No? I'm with Bill on this one. 00002020...

Comment: @BrianTiffin 000202020... is the HEX representation, converting to decimal he may be seeing `WS-RESULT:000035322350018592` displayed

Comment: TS/OP seen four hours ago. I am absolutely convinced they are collecting all the information they can, and will edit their question at any moment.

Comment: And while you are back, can you address the outstanding issues here?

Answer (score 0):

I have just worked with a code example involving BINARY, DISPLAY, and DISPLAY EDITED numeric data items.

The compiler will make certain adjustments internally when moving data items with different type descriptions.

As a general rule, you should avoid moving data to another area that is defined differently.  Otherwise, you will get the diagnostic message about "moving alpha to numeric may produce unexpected results".  That means the final result may not be what you wanted.

From my COBOL manual for the UNISYS system (IBM configuration may be different), PIC 9(18) BINARY consists of 63 bits or 7 ASCII bytes.  In your example, you are moving a 16 byte USAGE DISPLAY field to a 7 byte USAGE BINARY field.

This may appear not to be a big deal and you would assume that the compiler will make internal adjustments for the DISPLAY to BINARY conversion for the value.

But, the major issue with your data definition is that the sending and receiving data fields are NOT on word boundaries.  05 level data items are not placed internally in memory on a word boundary which means the transfer of such data fields is subject to portions of a computer memory word being taken apart and then converted to other data definition type.

In all likelihood, the final result of your 16 to 7 byte move instruction produced a gigantic binary value result which carried over to the last two MOVE commands.

The other major issue with the code is that the PIC X USAGE DISPLAY fields are synchronized LEFT while PIC 9 USAGE BINARY fields are synchronized RIGHT within the computer, so the data alignment, bit positions within a computer word, and forced data type conversion generated the "same data move mistake" regardless of the original value in WS-CHARS.  The bottom line is that you have bad coding.

To understand this better, you need to take assembly language programming which I was programming with originally.

Comment: Seven bytes? Since when has ASCII had 9-bit bytes? We don't know what COBOL or OS was used, but I'd expect 64 bits were used for the 9(18) binary anyway.

Comment: Perhaps you have to take care of boundary-alignment on a Unisys system. I don't know of anywhere else you'd need to bother. OP hasn't been seen for more than a year, so don't expect much feedback from them.